# Invoking WCF Service through Javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, web-services

How can I access the WCF Service through JavaScript?
My problem is, I have to access the operation contracts through the JavaScript (my website is not Ajax enabled).
Previously for calling .asmx web services, 
I am using the following code snippet

```
var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xmlHttp.open("POST", URL, false);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send(payload);
xmlData = xmlHttp.responseXML;
```

where url is my webservice location.

Now if I am trying to consume the wcf service in the same manner, I am not able to.
Many techies are explaining through AJAX approach, 
I need an approach without AJAX.

Answer (score 4):

By using XMLHTTP you ARE using ajax.

There's a full example here:

[jQuery AJAX calls to a WCF REST Service](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code on the link that I have sent before. Sure U can implement it yourself but it well be a huge effort duplication.

First, your WCF service must have:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Then, on the javascript side, change the

```
"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

To

```
"Content-Type", "application/json"
```

Remember that the response will be json formated, so having a parser could be useful.

Why you don't want to use external libs?