# calling wcf service through Java script

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using vs 2010- mvc3 with aspx (not raiser type).
I try to use web service through J sciprt, but i got error unknown method.

In my privious project (mvc) using web serive (asmx); using asp:ScriptManager working fine

Answer (score 0):

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wcfinjavascript.aspx

[Invoking WCF Service through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283891/invoking-wcf-service-through-javascript/283921#283921)

and many more...